# How to get week days in php?

Tags: php

I want to get Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... using php function.

I have only numeric values for those like 1,2,3..7 where

1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday
...
7 = Sunday.

Can anybody help me regarding this.

Thanks,

Kanji

Comment: @Kanji - your numeric values start from 0 and ended with 6 ???

Comment: @ajreal: I have consider 0 as monday, 1 as tuesday onwards.

Comment: @Kanji - so is ended with Sunday, which is 6? (one of the weired format), you should update your question to include this piece of information, otherwise **who the hall** will now, 0=monday, (see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), normally is 1-7 (monday-sunday) or 0-6 (sunday-saturday)

Comment: @Kanji - how come now is 1-7? haha ... what exactly is your data looks like ? do not influent by my comments

Comment: #ajreal : No i want from 1-7 as i mention in my edited question.. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), with the `$format` parameter as `l` (lowercase L).

Object Oriented style:

```
$object->format('l');
```

Procedural style:

```
date_format(DateTime $object, 'l');
```

You can create a DateTime object with [DateTime::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), and you can learn more about DateTime formats [here](http://php.net/date).

Comment: Thanks but can you give this in simple php style?

Comment: @Kanji First, you have to create a DateTime object, then use the procedural style.

Comment: Also, this solution may be overkill if you already have the number of the day of the week. In that case, [deceze's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551861/how-to-get-week-days-in-php/4551894#4551894) would be better.

Answer (score 6):

My personal favorite...

```
$day_start = date( "d", strtotime( "next Sunday" ) ); // get next Sunday
for ( $x = 0; $x < 7; $x++ )
    $week_days[] = date( "l", mktime( 0, 0, 0, date( "m" ), $day_start + $x, date( "y" ) ) ); // create weekdays array.
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you have is a numeric value and not a complete timestamp, by far the easiest way is this:

```
$weekdays = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', ...);
$weekday = 0;
echo $weekdays[$weekday];
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should give you the day of the week for today (ex. tuesday):

`<? echo date("l"); ?>`

or for a specific date you can use something like this:

`<? echo date("l",strtotime("10 September 2000")); ?>`

For more info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you have just a number that you are trying to convert to a day of the week, you could use the following:

```
function convertNumberToDay($number) {
    $days = array('Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    return $days[$number-1]; // we subtract 1 to make "1" match "Sunday", "2" match "Monday"
}
echo convertNumberToDay(3); // prints "Tuesday"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($day) {
    case 0 : echo "Monday"; break;//if $day = 0  it will print Monday
    case 1 : echo "Tuesday"; break;
    case 2 : echo "Wednesday"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$day = 2;
echo date('l', mktime(0,0,$day,0,1)); // Tuesday
?>
```

So you can create a simple function like this:

```
function getDayName($dayNo) {
    return date('l', mktime(0,0,$dayNo,0,1));
}
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/hrITc

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to convert 0 to "Monday", 1 to "Tuesday", etc. use an array.

```
$day_of_week = array
(
    0 => 'Monday',
    1 => 'Tuesday',
    2 => 'Wednesday',
    .
    6 => 'Sunday'
);

$day = 2;

echo $day_of_week[$day];
```

Comment: Sorry this is a duplicate of [deceze's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551861/how-to-get-week-days-in-php/4551894#4551894)