# How to get day of week by date on PHP?

Tags: php

I get date (ex. 2015-06-12) and i want to get day of week...

For example Monday = 1

```
$dateprog=$_GET['dateprog'];
$dow = date("N",$dateprog);
```

but it's not working

Comment: Try using DateTime http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get week days in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551861/how-to-get-week-days-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find day of week in php in a specific timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: `$dateprog` isn't a timestamp, it's just a string: `$dow = date("N",strtotime($dateprog));`

Comment: @MarkBaker this is the answer. just post it as an answer.

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4551879/3836908

Answer (score 3):

The variable $dateprog is in string format which you are extracting from the

> $_GET['dateprog']

and parsing it as a parameter to the date function. However, the date function takes timestamp or date format as its second parameter

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

See documentation : [Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

In order to convert the string to timestamp use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['dateprog']))
{
    $dateprog = $_GET['dateprog'];
    $dow = date("N",strtotime($dateprog));
    echo $dow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
if (!empty($_GET['dateprog'])) {
    $dateprog=$_GET['dateprog'];
    $dow = date("N",strtotime($dateprog));
    echo $dow; // will print the day number of the week
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just cast it to time:

```
$dateprog=$_GET['dateprog'];
$dow = date("N",strtotime($dateprog));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$dow = date("N",strtotime($dateprog));
```