# Get day of the next week by monday with php

Tags: php

i want to get the day of the next week with php..i need something like this

If today is monday, i want to display the days (es 18-19-20) of the next week, not of this week..the week start on monday...but it will work also if today is sunday..always the days of the next week..i can't found anything because i tried to use jddayofweek but i don't understand it maybe..i haven't found an italian guide..

I have a table which display the days in stringn form..so sunday monday etc, fir my problem i tried date() function but if i use +1 on the day i will have problem with february for example

Comment: share the code snippet

Comment: use `mktime()` function to add a week

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get week days in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551861/how-to-get-week-days-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're doing, but maybe something like:
`echo date("d", strtotime("monday next week"))`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you next Monday:

```
$date = date_create()->modify('monday next week');

echo date_format($date, "d");
```